# Excel VBA: How can I run code when any check box value changes in a Userform?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

How can I run code when any check box value changes in a Userform?

I am attempting to use a class module but the code is acting in a strange way that I don't understand.

The code will only recognize that the value of a checkbox has changed the very first time it happens if, and only if, there is a breakpoint set in the code for the _Change() event. All other instances it doesn't recognize any more changes.

Here is my code in Userform_Initalize()

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim ckCollection As New Collection
Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
Dim obj As clsCheckBoxes

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls

            If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.CheckBox _
       And Not TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.OptionButton _
       And Not TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.ToggleButton _       
       And Not ctrl.Name = "ckEditFileDescription" Then    'do not need this particular checkbox in this class module

                    Set obj = New clsCheckBoxes
                    Set obj.Control = ctrl
                    ckCollection.Add obj

             End If
 Next ctrl
 Set obj = Nothing
```

And here is my code in my class module clsCheckBoxes

```
Private WithEvents xlCheckBoxes As MSForms.CheckBox

Public Property Set Control(cK As MSForms.CheckBox)
    Set xlCheckBoxes = cK
End Property

Private Sub xlCheckBoxes_Change()

    Call CheckVisibility
    'This is the code I want to run when any of the checkboxes change
    'but it seems to only recognize the event if the "Call CheckVisibility" is a 
    'breakpoint, and even then, it will only recognize the first time a checkbox value 
    'is changed

End Sub
```

On a side note, "If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.CheckBox" is returning some of my option boxes and toggle buttons and I don't know why. The "Add Not" statements seem to fix it but it still seems strange that it's happening.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940596/excel-vba-userform-execute-sub-when-something-changes

Comment: This question is answered (including a code sample) at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34877566/how-make-vba-run-on-clicking-any-checkbox-in-a-userform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34877566/how-make-vba-run-on-clicking-any-checkbox-in-a-userform)